# Can not use the jsmpeg in react "Unexpected use of 'self'"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ffmpeg, onvif, jsmpeg

## code that i want to convert in React

```
 <body>
    <!-- <canvas id="videoCanvas" height="600" width="600"></canvas> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsmpeg.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var canvas = document.getElementById("videoCanvas");
      console.log(document.location.hostname);
     var url = "ws://localhost:9999/";
    </script>
    <div
      class="jsmpeg"
      data-url="ws://localhost:9999/"
      data-loop="true"
      data-autoplay="true"
      style="width:900px;"
    >
</div>
```

Can not change it to react format.When i try to convert it is giving jsmpeg error 
i.e

## code that i tried but get an error

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import "./jsmpeg.min.js"
const App =()=>{
    return(
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    )
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

## Error

/src/jsmpeg.min.js
Line 606:9:    Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
  Line 2771:13:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: The jsmpeg.min script cannot be imported into a React component, you need to import it in your main index.html file

Comment: i tried but it is not workink brother

Answer (score 0):

go to jsmpeg and change self with window.fetch